# Loop not working while creating loan amortization table using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, amortization

I am creating a loan amortization table using Vb.net. All working fine but my **loop** is not working correctly. It should show all the reducing monthly payments, balance one after another. My code for loop is given below:

```
    Listbox1.Items.Add("Nos" & vbTab & "Periodic" & vbTab & "Payment" & vbTab & "Payment" & vbTab & "Balance")
    Listbox1.Items.Add("" & vbTab & "Payment" & vbTab & "Interest" & vbTab & "Principal" & vbTab & "")
    Listbox1.Items.Add("__________________________________________________________________________________________")


    Dim a As Integer

    **For a = 1 To n
        monthly_Interest = (p * (txtbox_Rate.Text / 100) * (1 / 12))
        monthlyPrincipal = monthlyPayments - monthlyInterest
        balance = p - monthlyPrincipal
        Listbox1.Items.Add(a & vbTab & FormatCurrency(monthlyPayments, 2) & vbTab & FormatCurrency(monthly_Interest, 2) & vbTab & FormatCurrency(monthlyPrincipal, 2) & vbTab & FormatCurrency(balance, 2))
    Next**
```

Comment: Please read point 1 of the http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic guide. You need provide details regarding what is not working in your loop. Don't just dump your code here and expect it to get fixed.

Comment: I apologies for my mistake...I want the user to input rate of interest,duration and amount ...And after clicking on Calculate button it should display a loan amortization table. I have taken 'p' as the loan amount, n as the duration and renamed the textbox of rate of interest as   "txtbox_Rate"...... After calculation of monthly_Interest, monthlyPrincipal and balance it should display the details in the table...Please let me know if u need any other info

Comment: Thanks for the above clarification. Please add details regarding what is not working in your loop. If you are getting an error, please post an error message.

Comment: Presently the loop is giving the same calculation in other iteration......

Nos PeriodicPayment  PaymentInterest  PaymentPrinicpal  Balance 
1   $8,884.88        $1,000.00  $7,884.88       $92,115.12
2   $8,884.88        $1,000.00  $7,884.88              $92,115.12
3   $8,884.88        $1,000.00  $7,884.88              $92,115.12

But I want that ,in other iteration(such as step 2.3,etc)apart from Periodic Payment every column should change its values ......Please help

Comment: Hey I solved it..... Thanks you for your response

Comment: Looks like "Rubber Duck Debugging" helped (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :)